# What is the category name of words that can take 2 objects?

Tags: terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you call a verb which accepts 2 nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33509/what-do-you-call-a-verb-which-accepts-2-nouns)

- The function `f` assigns each value of `x` a value of `f(x)`.
- Please show me what you have done.
- I tell you the truth.

What is the category name of words that can take 2 objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammarians call them *ditransitive*.